# asp form submit button without inline javascript

Tags: asp.net

I want when a form gets submitted, trigger a function call on the server side. I want to use CSP on my website so no inline script is allowed (I know I can allow it but that's the whole point).

I have a submit button:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Register" OnClick="RegisterUser" UseSubmitBehavior="true"  />
```

But it generates this javascript and adds it to the button.

```
onclick="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(\"ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder$btnSubmit\", \"\", true, \"\", \"\", false, false))"
```

*the escaped quotes are actually &quot; but it looks nicer this way

I can't use the asp's own submit button and use `onClick` to trigger `RegisterUser` (like the code above) because of the inline script it uses. If I just submit the form using normal submit button, `RegisterUser` doesn't trigger. The only way I can think of is to check for form submits on page load and trigger `RegisterUser` then. Is there another way?

Comment: Yes. But I think you're going about this wrong. Your RegisterUser function on the server can call whatever functions it wants.

Comment: My problem is to bind a RegisterUser to submit. The example of the button is what I would use but because it has inline javascript I can't.

Comment: Have you tried swapping the use submit behavior value?

Comment: you need to switch to MVC

Comment: @mason It just swaps `type=submit` with `button`

Comment: @AdrianIftode believe me I know!

Comment: What is CSP? I'm thinking you can do some hacks though at the Render event, like to replace the generated html with yours and move the onclick in another place

Comment: What's wrong with checking the form submit on page load and calling the method from there, like you suggested? That's what asp framework does for you with the asp:Button control.

Comment: @Sami I was thinking that there should be event or something for submit, currently I just check `Request.Form` and see if it is empty or not.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say this is the simplest way.
HTML:

```
<button name='registerButton'>Register</button>
```

aspx.cs:

```
if (IsPostback && Request.Form.Allkeys.Contains("registerButton"))
{
    RegisterUser();
}
```